# How can I find the python package name in any linux distribution?

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I want to be pull up the name python-3.5, python3.6m, etc.

When I do a "python --version" it's not in the correct format and it could be subjected to change. Is there any way to find the names generally in /usr/bin/* folder? Or should I just grep for it and assume that it'll always be in that directory for other users?

I am using the command "$pkg-config python-3.6m --ldlibs --cflags" and I would like to have a dynamic way to find the "python-3.6m" in that line so that the user doesn't have to change it every time they run it on a different version of Python.

Comment: Well, you could use `pythonVV-config` ... but the `sysconfig` module has the information you need

Comment: @o11c neither neither of these commands can be found on my linux distro. Is there a more widely used command?

Comment: Use of `pythonVV-config` is pretty common I think - usually there's a symlink farm, `python-config (if in a venv) -> python3-config -> python3.5-config -> python3.5m-config`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'python-' + sysconfig.get_config_var('LDVERSION')`. There are numerous other variables in that module.

Note that this won't work on non-cpython implementations, but they usually require special cases for building anyway.